# How do I close the original program using a second program that has been called in by the original in python

Tags: python, exit, calling-convention

Trying to set up a pygame main menu for a game which closes once a level is selected and opened

Tried `Subprocess.Popen(app)` and simply tried `sys.exit()` after calling the second script in the original but doesn't work for me. I Tried closing original code at start and at end of code in second program.

Comment: Why are you spawning new processes for levels in the first place? This seems like some attempt at state machines but using process spawning and termination instead of what are essentially flags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.